# Connecting to Route53 API from Google App Engine using boto

Tags: python, google-app-engine, boto, amazon-route53

I am getting the following messages:

```
2014-02-04 09:55:10.515 encountered error exception, reconnecting
2014-02-04 09:55:10.515 establishing HTTPS connection: host=route53.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'port': 443, 'timeout': 70}
```

It continues to retry for awhile and then I see the error:

```
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://route53.amazonaws.com/2012-02-29/hostedzone Error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

This is using python boto 2.24.0 and I tested both locally using the SDK and when deployed on GAE.

The code I'm using breaks at:

```
zone = conn.get_zone("myzonename.com.")
```

It's gotta be something simple. I tried going back and using older versions of boto to see if it was a regression but no such luck.
The AWS credentials are defined as environment variables in app.yaml. The SSL library is enabled as well using:

```
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

If I run the code directly in Python without using the App Engine SDK, everything works OK. But when the HTTP requests go through the URLFetch API there seems to be a problem.

Comment: Do you have an egress firewall on your instance?  From the error message it looks like it is just unable to reach the route53 host.

Comment: Yeah I know it certainly looks that way, but unfortunately it's not that. That would be an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to Google's httplib in "google/appengine/dist27/gae_override". Notice that it says it can't connect to **http**://route53.amazonaws.com.

Google's HTTPConnection class defines _protocol as 'http', and will use that in getresponse() unless _url starts with the protocol. In my testing, _url is only the path after the host, so Google's httplib uses HTTP instead of HTTPS, which Amazon refuses. Packet traces confirm this.

The question of how to get it to work with Google's httplib remains. I'll update this as I learn more, but this is at least a start.

Edit: Requests strips everything but the path in adapters.py/HTTPAdapter/request_url, saying it's all we should use unless using a proxy. I don't know why that would be, but I'm not familiar with requests. (Edit: Oh, because it's in the HTTP request. Der.)

Edit 2: (Will clean this up once I've figured this out. Stream of consciousness right now.) The connection is being created as an HTTPSConnection, but for some reason _protocol is staying set to "http".

Edit 3: In Requests' connection.py, HTTPSConnection inherits from HTTPConnection, which inherit's from Google's HTTPConnection. The HTTPSConnection from Google's httplib is never used.

Edit 4: Python's standard httplib uses self.connect() to define self.sock(), which is what it uses to send data to the server. Requests overrides these methods in its connection classes. Google's httplib does the actual data sending in getresponse(), using urlfetch. This would seem to make it fundamentally incompatible with the way Requests works.

Not sure how to fix this. Multiple inheritance in Request's HTTPSConnection class? Manually setting _protocol to work with GAE? Nothing particularly pretty comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks for digging into it. I ended up manually kinda forcing it to work. See the answer that I added.

Comment: Requests explicitly doesn't support GAE. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by editing boto/connection.py

On line 909 in connection.py change:

```
connection.request(request.method, request.path,
```

to

```
connection.request(request.method, "https://route53.amazonaws.com" + request.path,
```

This is not a pretty fix. I'm hoping that the kind folks at boto will notice this and find a way to properly fix it so that it works out of the box on GAE.